# Inserting HEX code in SQL database

Tags: php, sql, forms, hex

I tried to insert a hex code to an SQL database by PHP, but it cannot be done. I tried to UNHEX but it does not give any results.
Input code:

```
<input type="color" name="color">
```

Inserting PHP code:

```
$color = $_POST['color'];
$query = "INSERT INTO `kolor` (`color`) VALUES (UNHEX($color))";
```

Comment: Could you be more specific? What doesn't work for you? As far as I understand the question, all you want to do is to store a hex color code such as `#000000` in your database, correct?

Comment: What are you expecting this to store? `unhex` convert each pair of characters in the argument to their ascii representation, but for anything higher than **7F**, this isn't going to return what you're expecting. HTML 5 color inputs also pass the leading #, so you'd need to trim that first if you're trying to convert this to RGB values/etc.

Comment: Responding to Simon's question: Yes that's all

Comment: Responding to Iainn's question: I want to store hex color code such as #000000 or #FFFFFF

Comment: @NiceGuy when responding to a person in particular, you need to ping them as I did for you here, using the `@member` method. They may no longer be present.

Comment: @NiceGuy just store the color code in your database, for instance as a `char(7)` (or `char(6)` if you trim the `#` what I personally would do). There's no need for `hex()` or `unhex()`.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you don't need `UNHEX()`, just store as it is.

`PDO` is nice and safely way to execute your query.

Example:

```
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$db   = 'test';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset", $user, $pass, $options);

$sql = "INSERT INTO `kolor` (`color`) VALUES (:color)' ";

$data = [
  "color" => $_POST['color'], 
];

$stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($data);
```

You can read more about `PDO` at https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Answer (score 0):

Make this :

```
$query = "INSERT INTO kolor (color) VALUES ('$color')";
```

But becarfull because you have a big SQL Injection with this syntax you need to prepare your request before.

For more information : https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_injection

Comment: How to prepare my request? I am using Phpmyadmin.